# Appcelerator platform organization team roles

Tags: appcelerator

On platform.appcelerator.com you can manage organizations and teams. We can assign different roles to team members of Administrator, Developer or Collaborator.

What are the distinctions between these 3 roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These roles are described in the 4.4.0 release notes:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Dashboard_4.4.0_Release_Note

```
Dashboard 4.4.0 introduces the capability to assign your users different roles that grants them differently rights to the dashboard. Those roles and rights are:

Org Admin - user has admin rights over your organization's Dashboard
Developer - user who has general developer rights
Collaborator - developer role (any license with collaboration enabled) from another organization who has access to your organization without taking up a license
Insight - user who has a "read-only" access such as viewing performance management, crash analytics, and query builder results to the team's assigned apps
In addition to these user roles, you can add the following features to your roles:

Support
Test (available for enterprise only)
Performance management (included to enterprise)
```

I've asked for it to be integrated in the documentation as well:
    https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDOC-2468